# The inequality $k(n-1)<n^2-2n$ for all odd $n$ and $k<n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How one can prove the following statement:

$k(n-1)<n^2-2n$ for all odd $n$ and $k<n$

*Tried so far*:  induction on $n$, graphing, and rewriting $n^2−2n$ as $(n−1)^2−1$.

Comment: What are your thoughts, what have you tried?

Comment: Hint: $n^2-2n = (n-1)^2-1$.

Comment: I tried many things: induction on $n$, graphically even and rewriting $n^2-2n$ as $(n-1)^2-1$

Comment: @Alufat According to NickC, the statement is actually false?

Comment: @BCLC Yeap, but is not a totally lost cause :)

Answer (score 4):

This isn't true.

Take $k=4$, $n=5$. We have $4(5-1)=16$ and $5^2-2\cdot 5=15$.

Answer (score 2):

Look, you should do something like that

\begin{align} &k(n-1) < n^2-2n \\
\iff &k(n-1) < (n-1)^2-1 \quad\text{(subtract $k(n-1)$ from both sides)}\\
\iff &0 < (n-1-k)(n-1)-1 \\
\iff &1 < (n-1-k)(n-1) \quad\text{(divide both sides by $(n-1)$)} \\
\iff &(n-1)^{-1}  < (n-1-k)
\end{align}

Since a counterexample to $n=1$ was already given in the comments, let's take $n\geqslant 3$ (just to have $\frac{1}{n-1} < 1$). Note that $\frac{1}{(n-1)}$ is a number in $(0,1)$, while $n-1-k$ is an integer, so the inequality is true iff $n-1-k>0$, that is, when $k<n-1$. So you should restate your claim:

> $k(n-1) < n^2-2n$ for all $n\geqslant 3$ and $k<n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Following the hint that $n^2 - 2n = (n-1)^2 - 1$

$k(n-1) < (n-1)^2 - 1$

Since $k < n$, we can take $k = n-1$ to derive a counter example.

$(n-1)^2 < (n-1)^2 - 1$

$1 < 0$.

So, taking $k=n-1$ always gives a counter example.